# How to recognise on which site the content is being rendered?

Tags: post-formats, images

I've created a child theme basing on twenty twelve.

Since I present the content a little bit different on home and on the archive page, I'd like to know inside `content-[format].php` on which page the post is being rendered. Then, I can decide which image size I can present.

How can I know it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the global `$template`. The following function returns the [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.basename.php) of the template file being used: `index`, `archive`, etc.

```
function get_template_name_wpse_85011()
{
    global $template;
    $filename = basename( $template, '.php' );
    return $filename;
}
```

And use it in your template with something like:

```
$templat = get_template_name_wpse_85011();
switch( $templat )
{
    case 'index':
        // do index
        break;
    case 'archive':
        // do archive
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```